# Google AdSense Alternative with PayPal as payment method

Tags: advertising, google

I am looking for Google AdSense Alternative with PayPal as a payment method.

I am looking to find something similar to Google AdSense ads format. I am not planning to use annoying popups/popunders or push notifications.
My website has few thousands visitors monthly.
Any hints would be highly appreciated.